# How to call a void method in a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, web

How can I call the void-method berechne2() in a JSP?
The way I trying doesn't work
Error: The operator + is undefined for the argument String, void

```
<html>  
<body>  
    <%! int zahl = 12; %>  
    <%! public int berechne() {
        return zahl * zahl;
    }
    %>
    <%! public void berechne2(int zahl) {
        zahl = zahl * zahl;
    }
    %>
    <%= "Zahl: " + zahl %><br>
    <%= "Quadrat davon: " + berechne() %>
    <%= "Quadrat davon: " + berechne2(zahl) %>      // here
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: What do you expect `<%= "Quadrat davon: " + berechne2(zahl) %>` to do exactly? How do you expect to concat `Quadrat davon:` with the result of a **`void`** method? P.S. scriptlets have been extremely bad practise for at least a decade now; if I were you, I'd forget they even exist.

Comment: I want the same output like in "<%= "Quadrat davon: " + berechne() %>". I have to do this with scriplets. Thats the better way?

Comment: Right, good. Now, we know that `berechne()` returns an `int`. This is converted to a `String` during concatenation - so for example you might get "Quadrat davon: 3". Now, please tell me what this output should be for a method that **does not return anything**, i.e. a `void` method.

Comment: so the void method is useless? I dont get you.

Comment: You tell me. What will the output be if the code were to magically work? What would the result of `<%= "Quadrat davon: " + berechne2(zahl) %>` be when `zahl = 12`?

Comment: the result -> 144  because 12 * 12

Comment: Okay, so `zhal` is now `144`. Fine. But what is the **exact text** of `<%= "Quadrat davon: " + berechne2(zahl) %>`, and why?

Comment: I have a return- and void-method. I only wanted to try how they work in a jsp. Ok i see. There is missing one line of code,...Maybe "  System.out.println(zahl); " after the "zahl = zahl * zahl;"

Comment: @HansBaum You have nothing to display so just don't put the call   inside   <%= %>  tags. put it iside <% %> instead. <%berechne2(zahl);%>. However Boris is completely right these way of coding is outdated...

Comment: my teachers are outdated too :D

Answer (score -1):

I think you should make a different approach, not like this. It's to either make a `scriplet` or a `servlet` and call it when needed on a `jsp` page.

In web applications, which I assume you are trying to build, compile a java class into a `.class` file and put it into WEB-INF/classes in the applications .war directory.

Now, to import and use the code on a `jsp`.

Example:

`<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>`

or some other class:

`<%@ page import="mypackage.myClass1%>`

And if you wish to import multiple classes, just add `,` in between:
<%@ page `import="mypackage.myClass1,mypackage2.myClass2,....,mypackageN.myClassN" %>`

Good luck! :D

Comment: The good way is to build all the methods in a java class and than call these from a jsp?

Comment: I am doing it this way, in some cases I do just put the code between <%@...%>, however, I think that this approach would be better. :)

Comment: It is a good method to use a [taglib](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaiy.html). JSP's should not import, call or otherwise have any access to Java classes. This recommendation was dated a decade ago, now it's irresponsible.